# How to run Jive with root user

Tags: hadoop, jive

I am using JIVE for testing some scripts in my server. Only root user has permission to execute that scripts. Can someone help me out how to execute JIVE with root user ?

Comment: You mean run the script with `sudo`?

Comment: I tried with sudo also but it is not working as jive is in some other machine

Comment: I don't know what jive is, so I can't really help you. Typically, in order to run a program as a user, the process running that program must be also running as that user. If it's on a separate machine, then ssh to it